# Why are there streams in the HttpURLConnection API?

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection

From what I understand about HTTP, it works like this: The client assembles a message, consisting of some header fields and (possibly) a body and sends it to the server. The server processes it, assembles its own response message and sends it back to the client.

And so I come to the question:

**Why are there all of a sudden streams in `HttpURLConnection`?**

This makes no sense to me. It makes it look like there is a continuous open channel. At what point does the message actually get sent to the server? On `connect`? On `getInputStream`? When trying to read from the stream? What if I have payload, does it get sent at a different time then? Can I do write-read-write-read with just a single connection?

I'm sure I just haven't understood it right yet, but right now it just seems like a bad API to me.

I would have more expected to see something like this:

```
HttpURLConnection http = url.openConnection();
HttpMessage req = new HttpMessage;
req.addHeader(...);
req.setBody(...);
http.post(req);

// Block until response is available (Future pattern)
HttpMessage res = http.getResponse();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO `HttpURLConnection` has indeed a bad API. But handling the input and output message as streams is a way to deal efficiently with large amounts of data. I think all other answers (at this moment 5!) are correct. There are some questions open:

> At what point does the message actually get sent to the server? On connect? On getInputStream? When trying to read from the stream?

There are some triggers when all collected data (e.g. headers, options for timeout, ...) is actually transmitted to the server. In most cases you don't have to call `connect`, this is done implicitly e.g. when calling `getResponseCode()` or `getInputStream()`. (BTW I recommend to call `getResponseCode()` before `getInputStream()` because if you get an error code (e.g. 404), getInputStream will throw an Exception and you should better call `getErrorStream()`.)

> What if I have payload, does it get sent at a different time then?

You have to call `getOutputStream()` and then send the payload. This should be done (obviously) after you added the headers. After closing the stream you can expect a response from the server.

> Can I do write-read-write-read with just a single connection?

No. Technically this would be possible when using `keep-alive`. But `HttpURLConnection` handles this under the cover and you can only do one request-response roundtrip with an instance of this class.

**Making life easier**

If you don't want to fight with the horrible API of `HttpURLConnection`, you could have a look at some abstraction APIs listed on [DavidWebb](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/#background). When using `DavidWebb`, a typical request looks like this:

```java
Webb webb = Webb.create();
String result = webb.post("http://my-server/path/resource")
    .header("auth-token", myAuthToken)
    .body(myBody)
    .ensureSuccess()
    .asString()
    .getBody();
```

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer. DavidWebb looks pretty neat, I'll give it a try. Did you write it?

Comment: Yes. I haven't found a way to efficiently reuse parts of the code necessary to deal with HTTP requests other than copy and paste. And as my Android app already weighs about 3 MB, I didn't want to add additional 600 kB for existing libraries like `unirest` or `restlet`. I hope you file bugs or wishes at [github](https://github.com/hgoebl/DavidWebb/issues).

Answer (score 2):

while the underlying transport does take place using individual packets, there's no guarantee that what you think about as a single http request/response will "fit" in a single http "packet". in turn, there's also no guarantee that a single http "packet" will fit in a single tcp packet, and so on.

imagine downloading a 20MB image using http. its a single http "response" but i guarantee there will be multiple packets going back and forth between the browser and the website serving it up.

every block is made up of possibly multiple smaller blocks, at each level, and since you might start processing the response before all the different bits of it have arrived, and you really dont want to concern yourself with how many of them there are, a stream is the common abstraction over this.

Answer (score 1):

Here the Http protocol works on Connection-Oriented TCP connection. So internally, it creates a TCP connection. then send http request on that and receive the response back. then drop the TCP Connection. that is why two different streams are there.

Answer (score 1):

Because streams are the generic way to push data between two places in Java, and that's what the HTTP connection does. HTTP works over TCP, which is a streamed connection so this API mimics that.

As for why it isn't abstracted further - consider that there is no size limits in HTTP requests. For example a file upload can be many MB or even GB in size.

Using a streamed API you can read data from a file or other source and stream it out over the connection at the same time without needing to load all that data into memory at once.

Answer (score 1):

A streaming response can be consumed on the fly not allocating up all the data in local memory, so it would be better from a memory point of view, for instance if you are to parse a huge json file doing this from stream and discards the raw data after it has been consumed. And in theory the parsing can begin as soon as the first byte has arrived.

And it is [getInputStream](http://varun-anand.com/images/HttpURLLibrary.jpeg) that does the send/receive part as well as initiating the creation of the underlying socket

Answer (score 1):

*TCP* is a byte stream. The body of an HTTP request or response is an arbitrary byte stream. Not sure what kind of API you were expecting, but when you have byte stream data you get a byte stream API.